# React Error Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, onclick, arrow-functions

I'm running into an error on a React project.
I just want to call multiple functions on a onClick event. Right now I'm rendering this in a component:

```
render() 
    {         
        let more;
        if (this.pageCounter > 0 && this.pageCounter < 4)  // il button more per far vedere più stats non va renderizzato oltre la terza pagina, perché l'API non ci arriva.
            more = <button id="More" onClick={ this.loadNextPage }>More...</button>;
        if (this.pageCounter == 0)
        {
            more = null;
            this.pageCounter++;
        }
        if (this.pageCounter >= 4)
            more = null;
        
        return (
                <div>
                  <div>
                    <form className="PlayerSearch" onSubmit={(event) => { event.preventDefault(); } }>
                        <label htmlFor="gamertag">Xbox Live Gamertag:</label>
                        <input type="search" id="search-recent-matches" name="Gamertag" placeholder="Enter a Gamertag..."></input>
                        <button type="submit" onClick={() => { this.initializeVariablesAndCounters; this.fetchHaloMatches; }} >Search</button>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                  
                  <MatchTable recentMatches={ this.data }/>
                  { more }
                </div> 
            );    
    }
```

Inside the return statement, I returned a div with a button and I set the event handler:

```
<button type="submit" onClick={() => { this.initializeVariablesAndCounters; this.fetchHaloMatches; }} >Search</button>
```

When I run the code, it seems to initally load fine, but as soon as the browser renders the form and thus the button, I get:

```
Line 140:64:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 140:101:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
```

Line 140 refers to that submit button , so there must be something wrong in that onClick, yet I can't figure what; the last version with just one function call worked perfectly:

```
<button type="submit" onClick={ this.fetchHaloMatches } >Search</button>
```

But now I have the need to call two functions when the event triggers. I figured out I had to use a arrow function, but as I mentioned, something's wrong with my code:

```
<button type="submit" onClick={() => { this.initializeVariablesAndCounters; this.fetchHaloMatches; }} >Search</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually call your functions:

```
<button
  type="submit"
  onClick={() => {
    this.initializeVariablesAndCounters();
    this.fetchHaloMatches();
  }}
>
  Search
</button>;
```

Just writing the function name references it; you have to actually call it for it to execute.

When passing a function as a prop in React, you are effectively replacing the `onClick` function with your own, which will be called inside the component receiving it as a prop. However, when passing multiple functions, you are actually making use of a callback function (`() => {}`), which is the thing being passed. The inner functions still have to be called whenever that callback function is activated.

Basically, this:

```
<button
  type="submit"
  onClick={() => {
    this.initializeVariablesAndCounters();
    this.fetchHaloMatches();
  }}
>
  Search
</button>;
```

is the same as this:

```
const myCallbackFunction = () => {
  this.initializeVariablesAndCounters();
  this.fetchHaloMatches();
};

<button type="submit" onClick={this.myCallbackFunction}>
  Search
</button>;
```